# Django, How to detect login success event?

Tags: django, authentication

I have built a crm system using django, and I want to record the login information(the login user, the login time, the login ip address) of the successfully-logged-in user, how to detect the successfully logging event? So I can save the login_record table.My view code is like this:

```
  def custom_login(request, **kwargs):                                             

      if request.user.is_authenticated():                                          
          return redirect(settings.LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL, **kwargs)                   
      else:                                                                        
          return login(request, **kwargs)
```

Comment: save all the info after `request.user.is_authenticated()`? is that what you mean?

Comment: @SamueleMattiuzzo No, I want to save the information of the user right after he/she logged in successfully.

Comment: @SamueleMattiuzzo Now when the user is logged in, the page will redirect to the homepage, I want to add a function before the redirection takes place, so I need to detect the login-success event and record the information.

Comment: You may want to use login signal, https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/auth/#topics-auth-signals

Comment: @RogerLiu unless you use signals, the best place to do it is between that if and the redirect.

Comment: @SamueleMattiuzzo I think you misunderstand the if statement, it is used when the user has logged in and access the login url, I don't want a logged-in user to see the login form, so I redirect him to the homepage, and when the user successfully log in, the redirecting url is set in the settings.py